# CIFAR-10 TensorFlow CNN error op: 'ValueError: Dimensions must be equal

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am implementing the CNN as below, but I got this error:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 3072 for 'Add_1'
>   (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,10], [3072]

I have attached my partial code below, where I suspect the error is coming from.

```
weights = {
    'WC1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 32]), name='W0'),
    'WC2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]), name='W1'),
    'WD1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8 * 8 * 64, 64]), name='W2'),
    'WD2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, n_classes]), name='W3'),
    'WD3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128, 3072]), name='W3'),
    'out2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072, n_classes]), name='W3'),
}

biases = {
    'BC1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]), name='B0'),
    'BC2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name='B1'),
    'BD1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name='B2'),
    'BD2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072]), name='B3'),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]), name='B3')
}

def conv_net(x, weights, biases):
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['WC1'], biases['BC1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)
    conv1 = normalize_layer(conv1)

    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['WC2'], biases['BC2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
    conv2 = normalize_layer(conv2)

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['WD1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['WD1']), biases['BD1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    fc2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['WD2']), biases['BD2'])
    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2)
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc2, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    return out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are few points that you need to correct in order to get rid of the error:

- change `weights['WD2']` from `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, n_classes]), name='W3')` to `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, 128]), name='W3')`
- change `biases['BD2']` from `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072]), name='B3')` to `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128]), name='B3')`
- Add another key named `BD3` in the `biases` dictionary like below:

  `'BD3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072]), name='B3')`
- Add a fully connected layer named `fc3` before `out` layer:

  `fc3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc2, weights['WD3']), biases['BD3'])
   fc3 = tf.nn.relu(fc3)`
- Finally change input to the output layer from `fc2` to `fc3`:

  `out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc3, weights['out']), biases['out'])`
- There is no key `out` in your `weights` dictionary. So, you change `out2` key to `out` in the weights dictionary. I suppose this must be a typo.
- One more thing, please correct the names you have given in `weights` and `biases` dictionaries. You have used the same name multiple times.

**Modified Code:**

```
weights = {
    'WC1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 32]), name='W0'),
    'WC2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]), name='W1'),
    'WD1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8 * 8 * 64, 64]), name='W2'),
    'WD2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, 128]), name='W3'),
    'WD3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128, 3072]), name='W4'),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072, n_classes]), name='W5')
}

biases = {
    'BC1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]), name='B0'),
    'BC2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name='B1'),
    'BD1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name='B2'),
    'BD2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128]), name='B3'),
    'BD3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072]), name='B4'),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name='B5')
}

def conv_net(x, weights, biases):
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['WC1'], biases['BC1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)
    conv1 = normalize_layer(conv1)

    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['WC2'], biases['BC2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
    conv2 = normalize_layer(conv2)

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['WD1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['WD1']), biases['BD1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    fc2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['WD2']), biases['BD2'])
    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2)
    fc3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc2, weights['WD3']), biases['BD3'])
    fc3 = tf.nn.relu(fc3)
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc3, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    return out
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now, however I'm getting this error: "2019-06-22 23:33:20.925028: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:124] Allocation of 1310720000 exceeds 10% of system memory.

Comment: I suppose this error is related to your system memory, i mean related to your ram space.

Comment: Btw I can only have 2 fully connected layers, how can I modify it to remove "FC3" and return "out" after the "FC2"?

Comment: If so, then it's simple. Remove fc3 from conv_net(). Then remove 'WD3' and 'BD3' key-value pairs from weights and biases dictionary respectively.

Comment: Modify out in weights to 'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128, n_classes]), name='out')

Comment: replace fc3 in out to fc2

Comment: Thanks!, how should I modify the "out" bias for it?

Comment: It will remain the same: 'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name='out')

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question. I further want to reduce it to FC1 (one fully connected layer). Meaning "out=tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1....)". How can I modify it again?

Comment: so you want to use just one fully connected layer, i.e., fc1. In that case, modify out parameter of weights dictionary to 'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, n_classes]), name='out'). Remove fc2 an fc3 layers from conv_net().

Comment: Thanks, but I get another error. I have opened a new post for this since this comment chain is running long. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723858/cifar-10-tensorflow-nvalidargumenterror-see-above-for-traceback-logits-and-l

Comment: Appreciate your help on this!